UDF in Snowpark + DBT gives ModuleNotFoundError with group_by().apply_in_pandas()
I am using snowpark and DBT to do some data transformations and creating some views/table in Snowflake. My models have a structure like this one:
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

def model(dbt, session: Session):
    dbt.config(materialized="table")
    df = dbt.ref("<SOME_TABLE>")
    df_grouped = df.group_by(col('ID1_COL'), col('ID2_COL'))

    def transform_function(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """
        Function that transforms data and is to be used in a grouped dataframe
        """
        [...]
        return df_transformed

    final_df = df_grouped.apply_in_pandas(
        transform_function,
        output_schema=StructType([
            StructField("COL1", StringType()),
            StructField("COL2", BooleanType()),
            [...]
            StructField("COLN", FloatType()),
        ])
    )

    return final_df

I want to define the transform_function outside of the dbt model function. No matter what I try I get different errors, mainly this one:
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_module'

Post about similar problem: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5VI000009QRW00AO/groupbyapplyinpandas-gives-error
I tried @udf decorators, registering a function in multiple different ways but I haven't managed to do it. When the function is not used in the apply_in_pandas it seems to work.
I have also tried pandas_udf but it hangs for ages.
The only thing I haven't tried is writing a library in a separate file but ideally I would like to avoid this.

I'm trying to simplify the sample UDF to one that I can reproduce on my account. Do you mean this works fine, except when you move transform_function outside of model()?

Yes, that's exactly what I mean. In fact, other functions work fine but functions that get used in apply_in_pandas don't

@FelipeHoffa did you have a chance to look into this? thanks!
